# How to use jQuery to make a get request in Django without refreshing page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, rating

I have made a five star rating view with five buttons (no stars yet). It basically loads a page which does the rating and then comes back to the original page very quickly. How can I use jQuery to not refresh the original page but still make a call to the view and update my rating?

**views.py**

```
def RateBusiness(request, pk, rate):
    business = Business.objects.get(id=pk)
    defaults = {'rating': rate}
    BusinessRating.objects.update_or_create(business=business, user=request.user, defaults=defaults)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/business-detail/%s/' % pk)
```

Original page link : `domain/business-detail/2/`

Rating page link : `domain/business-detail/2/rate/1/`

**template**

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{% url 'rate-business' object.id 1 %}">1</a>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{% url 'rate-business' object.id 2 %}">2</a>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{% url 'rate-business' object.id 3 %}">3</a>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{% url 'rate-business' object.id 4 %}">4</a>
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{% url 'rate-business' object.id 5 %}">5</a>
</div>
```

Although the question says `without refreshing page`, I do need to refresh the `<p>` tag which shows the current rating, so that it gets updated after someone rates. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you need an ajax request instead.Also you may want to use a for loop in your template

Comment: I would have used a for loop if this was my final version, I don't think I'm going to use five buttons for rating. I will be trying Raty for my ratings, but I am very very new to Javascript, so I couldn't implement that, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). It is really simple using it with jQuery.

It will create async request on provided URL, in a success part you can change your value in `<p>` tag to show the average of rating.

**Edited** based on comment:
In your HTML, create `<p>` tag something like this

```
<p id="avg_rating"></p>
```

And your Ajax call shoud be:

```
    $.ajax({
    url:'{% your_url %}',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response); //response is value which you return from Django view
        $("#avg_rating").text(response); //this statment will fill `<p id="avg_rating">` with value you return from Django view
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using `jQuery.ajax('<url>')` and after that if I refresh the page, it shows the updated rating. Can u be more specific about how to refresh the `<p>` tag?

Comment: Will this code go in `onclick` attribute of the button? It's not working. Also, the response in my template is `{{ rating.rating__avg }}`.

Comment: It seems that the code is alright, but the variable I have in the original page does not get refreshed, so it keeps showing the old value. :-/

Comment: You mean variable provided as `{{ rating.rating__avg }}` in your template?
This is normal behaviour because, that is how Django template system works. You render your template just when page load. With Ajax you create asynchronous request and dynamically change with your return value. 
I don't know exactly what bother you, but you can simply create something like that: `<p id="avg_rating">{{ rating.rating__avg }}</p>` in your template, and then it will refresh when you create Ajax request and replace your value with `$("#avg_rating").text(response);`

Comment: You got the scenario correctly. But the variable doesn't reload unfortunately. Maybe because I'm using `{{ rating.rating__avg }}` in place of response, but then again, that IS my response. I'll get back to it after a bit of studying on AJAX. Thanks for your time. :)